# React/RCTEventEmitter.h not found with codepush and cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native

I am have quite the issue in diagnosing the cause of why my iOS react native build is failing. After diagnosing a few other errors, the issue im facing right now is that no matter what i try, the error **React/RCTEventEmitter.h not found** plagues me and my app. This is just a basic react-native app created by `react-native init`.

I tried just about every combination of the following below:

- changing the "Header Search paths"
- Deleting the *xcode/DeriveData* folder created
- "Deintegrating" pods
- pod install
- draging/dropping react-native-code-push xcodeproject/library directly to my app in xbox in *Libraries*
- xcode clean
- react-native link
- react-native link code-push
- removing codepush from Podfile
- removing the *ios/Pods* folder
- removing the *ios/Podfile.lock* file
- building the app manually with **xcodebuild** (same error)

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -workspace ios/myApp.xcworkspace -scheme myApp  archive -archivePath myApp.xcarchive -UseModernBuildSystem=NO CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
```

My react info is as follows(its a macOS VM):

```
    System:
      OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.1
      CPU: (4) x64 AMD Ryzen 7 1700X Eight-Core Processor         
      Memory: 102.70 MB / 4.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 11.11.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v11.11.0/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.13.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v11.11.0/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.7.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v11.11.0/bin/npm
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 11.2, macOS 10.13, tvOS 11.2, watchOS 4.2
    IDEs:
      Xcode: 9.2/9C40b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.4.1 => 16.4.1 
      react-native: 0.57.0-rc.0 => 0.57.0-rc.0 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
      react-native: 0.58.6
```

My Podfile is:

```
target 'myApp' do
  # Pods for AppCenter
  pod 'AppCenter/Crashes', '~> 1.13.0'
  pod 'AppCenter/Analytics', '~> 1.13.0'
  pod 'AppCenterReactNativeShared', '~> 1.12.0'
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for myApp


  platform :ios, '9.0'
  pod 'CodePush', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-code-push'

end
```

The exact error im facing is:

```
/Users/administrator/Desktop/BUILD/myApp/node_modules/react-native-code-push/ios/CodePush/CodePush.h:6:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTEventEmitter.h' file not found
#import "React/RCTEventEmitter.h"   // Required when used as a Pod in a Swift project
```

Although im pretty new to iOS development, it seems like the things i did above should fix the issue but it did not. The error seems pretty obvious but i dont know what else to do.

I know there is many articles on this issue but most the articles/issues i seen where resolvable but for some reason, the specific case im facing seems extraordinarily. I  was wondering if anyone has any other tips or faced a issue like this? Any help is massively appreciated!

Comment: So you got this error every time when you create a project with `react-native init`?

Comment: try using react-native upgrade

Answer (score 0):

The error is triggered [at this line](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/ios/CodePush/CodePush.h#L6) which is only required when used as a Pod in a **Swift Project**

```
#import "React/RCTEventEmitter.h"   // Required when used as a Pod in a Swift project
```

The issue seems to be caused from this [`pull` request](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/pull/627), I suggest you to use the latest version of [`react-native-code-push@5.6`](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/tree/v5.6.0) compatible with `react-native 0.57`.

Try the following to fix the problem

1) Make sure you correctly configured your `Podfile` for `Swift`
Add `use_frameworks!` to the podfile if your are using swift

```
# Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!
```

2) Re-Install and configure `react-native-code-push` to latest version `5.6`

```
npm uninstall react-native-code-push
npm install --save react-native-code-push@5.6.0
```

follow the [ios setup](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/v5.6.0/docs/setup-ios.md#plugin-installation-ios---cocoapods) and the [plugin configuration](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/v5.6.0/docs/setup-ios.md#plugin-configuration-ios)

4) Install the [`app center` as by instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/react-native)

**If the problem is not fixed**

5) [Add the following line](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/583#issue-185348433)  to `node_modules/react-native-code-push/ios/CodePush/CodePush.h`

```
#import "React/RCTEventEmitter.h"
```

or

```
#import "RCTEventEmitter.h"
```

or

```
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>
```

**If the above solution does not fix the problem**

6) [Remove the following line from `ios/AppDelegate.m`](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/pull/670#issuecomment-278164867)

```
#import "CodePush.h"
```

[and add](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/setup-ios.md#plugin-configuration-ios)

```
#import <CodePush/CodePush.h>
```

The problem is caused from the following lines of [`node_modules/react-native-code-push/blob/master/ios/CodePush/CodePush.h`](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/v5.6.0/ios/CodePush/CodePush.h#L6).
All `if` statements are failing (meaning that those classes are not available) and `line 6` is executing.

```
line 1 #if __has_include(<React/RCTEventEmitter.h>)
line 2 #import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>
line 3 #elif __has_include("RCTEventEmitter.h")
line 4 #import "RCTEventEmitter.h"
line 5 #else
line 6 #import "React/RCTEventEmitter.h"   // Required when used as a Pod in a Swift project
line 7 #endif
```

I am happy to help you further to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same/similar issue/s integrating CodePush with RNPM and CocoapPods.

I would advise you to install it manually, [option 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/react-native#plugin-installation-ios---manual). It worked on the first try.

I'm working on a very large project and experienced similar issues with iOS. What solved my issues was removing the "global" cache of the machine on which the build server lives. Also, try removing the Xcode Archives and Derived Data; and Podfile.lock.

Answer (score 0):

> ***This issue must be resolved this way***:

- Find and remove all the references of **`AppCenter`** ( use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> shortcut )
- Reinstall the packages
- Run **`pod install`** command from **/ ... / ios / ... /** folder in *Terminal*

Hope this helps.